# Registering Static Broadcast receiver in Oreo

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

I'm Working on a project which records incoming calls and outgoing calls,
but with Oreo static broadcast receivers (Broadcast receivers which are registered in the manifest) are not getting triggered.
if I register with context, the broadcast will not be triggered once app gets killed.

I want the broadcast receiver to work even if app is closed.

is there any possible way to achieve this Oreo? or any other alternative approach to achieve this?
any help will be appreciated.

I'm registering in manifest as below code

```
<application ...
  ..
    <receiver
            android:name=".PhoneCallReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: Could you paste your code here?

Comment: Its System restricted. I do not think there is way to omit this behaviour . have a look at [Broadcast Limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts)  if you already haven't. if you are using one of the listed Broadcast .

Comment: @ShaluTD I have pasted code

Comment: @ADM but Truecaller apps works fine in my Oreo phone. it shows call details before and after every call ends.

Comment: what info do you need ?

Comment: currently, if the user swipes and kills the app, the broadcast receiver is not getting triggered. the broadcast receiver only works if the app is active or the app is minimized. I want to know how can I make it work even if app gets killed.

Comment: no , i mean what are the out-going/incoming call details you need ? is calling number sufficient ?

Comment: yes, that's all i need only calling number

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some Broadcast Limitations in Oreo, it no longer supports to registering broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in app manifest. And NEW_OUTGOING_CALL is one of them, read [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts)

You can use PHONE_STATE action for your purpose as it hasn't categorized as a implicit broadcasts yet

```
public class StateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   // will trigger at incoming/outgoing call

    try {
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        String outgoingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

In manifest,

```
        <receiver android:name=".StateReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Also you need to add and check READ_PHONE_STATE permission

Comment: it works only if app is alive once the app gets killed broadcast will not get triggered. i want it to get triggred even if app is not alive just like truecaller app

Comment: PHONE_STATE isn't categorized here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html and i check with 8.1 emulator and it works fine even when app isnt alive, i dnt have a real device though

Comment: in my phone, if I swipe and cancel the app it's not triggering broadcast.

Comment: my phone is OnePlus 5t Oreo 8.1

Comment: I'll upvote your answer, ill accept once I get the complete solution

Comment: @Jayanth did u got your answer for this question ?

Comment: I upvoted this answer, and that's all I normally do when I find a solution, But I just wanted to say that this worked beautifully for me, and I like how concise it is!

Comment: Same issue, the broadcast receiver isn't being triggered, I do not close the app I simply switch to home screen then dial a number. I want to catch the broadcast within a break point while debugging.

Comment: not working when the app is closed from the recent app. any suggestions?

Comment: @Jayanth did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

There are some Implicit Broadcast Exceptions which you can find here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions and ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL is among them.

My similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51354698/1399483