# Running a service on Outgoing Calls in Oreo

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, outgoing-call

I'm developing an app which needs to run some code (Open Activity) whenever an call to specific number is performed.
In API 24 and lower it's fine, I register an implicit receiver in Manifest file and start my service in the specified class which extended BroadcastReceiver. In API 26 however you cannot register android.provider.Telephony.OUTGOING_CALL in a receiver since it won't work.

From Android documentation:

> Note: If your app targets API level 26 or higher, you cannot use the
>   manifest to declare a receiver for implicit broadcasts (broadcasts
>   that do not target your app specifically), except for a few implicit
>   broadcasts that are exempted from that restriction. In most cases, you
>   can use scheduled jobs instead.

I've read several articles like this one https://medium.com/@benexus/background-services-in-android-o-862121d96c95 on medium. There are solutions like `JobScheduler` or `Explicit Receiver`, however the first one is used for changes in network state and I couldn't find a way to trigger the job on OUTGOING_CALL event and the second one is valid until your activity is up and running.

Because of the nature of my application I need to listen for outgoing call whether the app is running or not. How to do that in API 26+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions that ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL is exempted from the Oreo restrictions you've mentioned.

If you have code that you've tried but it isn't working, then you should post that.